# May i open new activity in any layout

Tags: android, activitygroup

I want to open new child activity in the parent LinearLayout. Just similar like Tabs.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ActivityGroup` . Multiple activities can be inflated on a single activity using Activtygroup.